# How valid is a sortBy and a sortorder to receive only asc or desc?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to create a validation so that sortBy and sortOrder receive only the values ​​specified in the case of sortOrder "asc" or "desc".

```
public virtual IPagedList<Book> GetAllBooks(string name = null, string description = null, DateTime? createdAt = null, int bookPublisherId = 0, 
        int yearPublication = 0, int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue, string sortBy = "", string sortOrder = "asc", string searchTerm = "", 
        bool getOnlyTotalCount = false)
    {
        var query = _bookRepository.Table;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            query = query.Where(c => c.Name == name);

        ...

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            query = query.Where(c =>  
            c.Id.ToString().Contains(searchTerm) ||
            c.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
        }

        //add a parse to prevent erros/injecton
        query = query.OrderBy($"{sortBy} {sortOrder}");

        var books = new PagedList<Book>(query, pageIndex, pageSize, getOnlyTotalCount);
        return books;
    }
```

Comment: Why not make them an enum? If you SortOrderEnum.Asc.ToString("g") will give "Asc" for example

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of work, but if you first execute the same query with a forced false condition (ie `where 1 = 0`) to ensure the execution plan doesn't waste time trying to get data, you can use a DbDataReader to cycle through each of the columns to get the names.

Something like this:

```
DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

string[] validFieldNames = new string[reader.FieldCount];
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    validFieldNames[i] = reader.GetName(i);
```

And then check before you modify the SQL:

```
if (validFieldNames.Contains(sortField))
    // good to go
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is if aliases in the query will mess this up or not.